# 'Start rollout to beta' disabled in Play Store Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

I am ready to send my first app to beta testers, so i click on '**Manage Beta**' > '**Manage testers**'

[image: add a new List with one tester in it].

and '**Save**' and '**Resume**'

APK is uploaded > '**Review**'

The review summary says '*This release is ready to be rolled out.*', but the button labled with '**Start to rollout to beta**' is disabled: [image: disabled button].

Comment: Make sure you select at least 1 country in availability (defaults to no countries)

Answer (score 298, accepted):

To see what still needs to be done, you can hover your mouse over the grayed out checkmark. There will be a popup that tells you what you still need to finish.

[image]

Answer (score 131):

Saranga is right from my experience.  Before I could send out a beta version I had to ensure I had the images under store listing included.  Just look at the side bar (see image) and see whats greyed out and thats where the problem was for me.

[image]

Comment: this is the correct answer as of October 2017 :P Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if they said that somewhere on the page! Even a tooltip on the disabled button would be something.

Answer (score 92):

Make Sure the following are checked

[image]

Comment: Very helpful!  Also, you can hover over the checkmark to see what you are missing for the various categories.

Answer (score 78):

> **Update** : The answer below is outdated. These days you should see a list of options on the left, that have grayed out ticks in-front of them. Hover over the tick and it should display the list of tasks you need done to complete that category. Visit each of these items and complete them (make sure the icon becomes green - check the screenshot below) to enable the button.

[image: PlayStore application, items to complete]

Not sure whether this is the actual answer or what you are expecting, but I am stuck at the same place (I just created an account, application and a release. Saw the disabled button and started googling). However there is a link on the top right side of the screen (barely visible, i should add), with the text "Why can't I publish?". And when I click on it I get list of error messages(I think). So as of now i am stuck on that list. Probably, fixing them might enable the button.

Comment: I don't see such a link!

Comment: It used to, at the time of this answer. However nowadays, you should see a warning/harzard mark.on the items on the left side (items such "App Releases", "Store Listing", etc), if they are incomplete. Do them and the button should enable.

Comment: Make sure that you have no exclamation mark in the left menu. Complete the Store Listing, Content Rating and Pricing & Distribution too!

Comment: When I tried this there was no warning or hazard mark on the left side items. There was a subtle greyed out icon on some of the sections that turned green when it was later completed, and this was what was preventing me from publishing my test release.

Comment: This is really weird UX. They should show a clearly visible message of why the button is disabled!

Comment: @lxx this is exactly what i said to my colleague when i saw the greyed out button.

Answer (score 7):

This can happen if payment for a recently created account is still processing, even if all mandatory sections are completed. I just created an account and I had this issue. I realized that my payment for the account creation was still processing. Once it's processed it's possible to publish the app.

Answer (score 6):

1. You have to add "Content rating", "Pricing & Distribution" information first so all checkboxes at the left are green
2. Then you have to click `Save`

Then you'll be able to click `Review`.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to make sure that you made it available in at least one country.
By default not one country is selected!

Answer (score 3):

If this is your first app, the problem will be due to payment processing which can take up to 48 hours according to your Google Play Developer Console under Account Details. Here is the actual text:

Payment Pending

Your payment is still processing, which will take up to 48 hours.

You can already start to upload APKs and prepare Store listings but not publish any applications yet.

We will notify you when the payment went through and you can publish your applications.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case I had to agree to "Content guidelines" and "US export laws" listed under "Consent" in "Pricing & distribution" section.

Answer (score 2):

They are missing a tooltip over the disabled button that should read something like: "Please make sure there are no warnings in sections on the left sidenav to enable publishing."

If you only see green checkmarks in the other sections you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

It will be active when nothing on left is grey but green ticked as shown[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICOhL.png)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to complete the Store listing, Pricing & distribution and Content rating before you can publish the app, once these task have been completed you should be able to publish the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your payment may not have cleared yet. It takes 48 hours after creating your account.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. In addition of all this you need to tick **App Content** tab also . Check out the details : [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9285070?hl=en)